# How to pass arguments to a function inside

Tags: php

I am using the Intervention Image Library to facilitate my card creation. For this I created a class where it would be easier to add texts on these cards.

Part of the code where this method is:

```
<?php
    use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

    class Cards Extends Image {

    private $image;

        [...]

        public function addText($text, $x, $y, $textSize, $font, $color, $align, $valign, $angle) {
                $this->image->text($text, $x, $y, function($font) {
                    $font->file($font);
                    $font->size($textSize);
                    $font->color($color);
                    $font->align($align);
                    $font->valign($valign);
                    $font->angle(0);
                });
            }
     }
?>
```

My question is, I'm having trouble passing the arguments of the addText method to the function($font). How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: You can also store them in your Cards class by using $this->myvar = ...;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the callback for [text()](http://image.intervention.io/api/text) only accepts the Font object, so use `use()` to pass them in:

```
$this->image->text($text, $x, $y, function($font) use($textSize, $color, $align, $valign)
{
    $font->file($font);
    $font->size($textSize);
    $font->color($color);
    $font->align($align);
    $font->valign($valign);
    $font->angle(0);
});
```